# Jitterbit - How to pass json request body to the Http connector (POST/Patch)

Tags: jitterbit

In Jitterbit cloud studio I want to pass below JSON as a Request Body to the HTTP Connector (PATCH/POST) but I do not see option for it I only see Request Headers, Request Parameters & Additional Settings which accepts only Key Value data.

As per my understanding I can set Request Body via Jitterbit Api variable ($jitterbit.api.request.body) but not sure how and where within HTTP connector I can do that?

**JSON Request Body**

```
{
    "custom_fields": [
        {
            "id": 6449064007,
            "value": "Passed"
        },
{
            "id": 545,
            "value": "www.test.com"
        }

    ]
}
```

[image: HTTP PATCH ADDITIONALSETTINGS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two primary options:

1. In your operation, just before the HTTP connector for the POST, you can add a transformation. That transformation would have the JSON schema and you can either hard-code those values (if that's truly the only body you would ever send in the POST call) or complete a mapping from a source schema. This is a basic [transformation pattern](https://success.jitterbit.com/cloud-studio/cloud-studio-reference/operations/operation-validity/#operationvalidity-transformation-pattern), with the HTTP connector as the target activity.
2. If you are calling the HTTP connector through a script, such as through the [WriteFile](https://success.jitterbit.com/cloud-studio/cloud-studio-reference/functions/file-functions/#filefunctions-writefile) function, the file contents can passed in the function call. Those contents would be the stringified version of the JSON.

Comment: it looks like 1st option should work for me and yes values are supposed to be harcoded in this scenario. However I am getting Error in execution patch activity. Exception is Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries. I even escaped the input json in a variable before calling HTTP Patch and then within Patch -> Additional Settings set key as [jitterbit.api.request.body] and value as [patch_requestbody]
Example: 
$patch_requestbody= {\"custom_fields\": [{\"id\": 6449064007,\"value\": \"Passed\"}]}

I have also attached image to my post.

Comment: (1/2) The jitterbit.api.request.body variable represents the body from a request that was passed INTO your operation. It is used when you are working with a custom API--in other words, when you are using an operation with the API connector (https://success.jitterbit.com/cloud-studio/cloud-studio-reference/connectors/api/). That doesn't appear to be the case here and there is likely no need for that variable.

Comment: (2/2) The additional settings are not related to the request body. You should not be trying to add the request body there. There are only certain settings supported; see https://success.jitterbit.com/cloud-studio/cloud-studio-reference/connectors/http-v2/patch-activity/#step-1-enter-a-name-and-specify-settings.

As long as you have a transformation alongside your PATCH activity in the operation, the PATCH will inherit the request schema and values from the transformation.